# Force download attachments from specific folder in a Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, download, attachment

I wanna to add Download link button using

```
<a href="<?php download_paper($id) ?>">Download</a>
```

After Searching on the internet I got that code:

```
$file_obj = new FileData($_REQUEST['id']);

    // Added this check to keep unauthorized users from downloading - Thanks to Chad Bloomquist
    checkUserPermission($_REQUEST['id'], $file_obj->READ_RIGHT, $file_obj);

    $realname = $file_obj->getName();

    if (isset($revision_id)) {
        $filename = $revision_dir . $request_id . ".dat";
    } elseif ($file_obj->isArchived()) {
        $filename = $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['archiveDir'] . $_REQUEST['id'] . ".dat";
    } else {
        $filename = $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['dataDir'] . $_REQUEST['id'] . ".dat";
    }

    if (file_exists($filename)) {
        // send headers to browser to initiate file download
        header('Cache-control: private');
        header('Content-Type: '.$_GET['mimetype']);
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $realname . '"');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
        header('Pragma: public');
        readfile($filename);
    } else {
        echo msg('message_file_does_not_exist');
    }
```

Here $revision_dir = $GLOBALS['CONFIG']['revisionDir'] . '/'. $_REQUEST['id'] . '/';

But I wanna download files from sitename.com/pdm-uploads/

Comment: I'm confused.  Why not use just a normal `href`?

Comment: <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ).'pdm-uploads/'. $download->realname ?>">Download</a>

Comment: Like this?
But it's only show attachment
I wanna download

Comment: Why not just do `<a href="path/to/your/download/file.dat">download</>`.? Why mess around with all this `php`? I don't see the point/

Comment: I am probably missing something obvious, but maybe if you explain what it is I am missing then I can be in a better position to help.

Comment: I have an attachments in a specific folder and I want them to force download. Now theses are open in a browser. I used <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ).'pdm-uploads/'. $download->realname ?>">Download</a> but I wanna them force to download

Comment: So you want them to download without the user clicking the link?

Comment: Thanks I got my answer

Comment: If you figured out the answer, you can write it in an **answer** (not an edit to your question or a comment, but an actual answer) and then mark it as correct by clicking the green checkmark.  This is allowed and even encouraged!  And it's a great way to share your knowledge with others.  Glad it worked out for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Leave the above code and simply add download in `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ).'path/'. $download->realname ?>" download>Download Now</>
```